# VBA reference to named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code in which I have tried to applied 3 filters, now what I want is, to apply this filter criteria based on named range
I have stored relevant value in specific cell and given names to that range

for first criteria i.e. >=200 named range is `VOLUME`

for second criteria i.e. >=0.07 named range is `MOVE`

for third criteria i.e. >=400 named range is `STRENTH`

So what are the changes that I need to make in following code?

```
Sub FILTER2()

'FILTER CRITERIA
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=200", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=">=0.07" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=">=400" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges)

Comment: Can you clarify which value is in your named range? Is it `200` or `>=200`? If the first, your criteria should be `">=" & Range("Volume").value`. If the second it should just be `Range("Volume").value`

Comment: value is in my named range is 200

Comment: You might want to refrain from using `ActiveSheet`. Since you will also want to refer to a specific sheet holding your named ranges, a `With` statement seems at place here.

Comment: I got your point, thank you to all of you for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you might want to consider a `With` statement, better not to refer to `ActiveSheet`

```
Sub FILTER2()

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    .Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter 6, ">=" & .Range("VOLUME")
    .Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter 21, ">=" & .Range("MOVE")
    .Range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter 28, ">=" & .Range("STRENTH")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it helped me a lot, thq for giving your valuable time to share ans.

Answer (score 0):

you can try defining a variable to contain the value of your named range.
Named Range in your sheet as "Volume" then i can store that value in var namedRange1.

example below:

```
Sub FILTER2()  

namedRange1 = range("Volume")

'FILTER CRITERIA
ActiveSheet.range("$A$2:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & namedRange1, _
    Operator:=xlAnd
```

....same with the other lines, just define new variable to contain new named range